# How to check the category collection is empty or not in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, category, collection

I am getting the subcategories of a main category like this(this file is in root folder)

```
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$subcategory_1 = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load(4);//My category Id
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
```

From this collection how can i check is there any subcategory is available or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$subcategory_1 = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load(4);
$children = $subcategory_1->getAllChildren(true);
if(!empty(children)){
  // Sub Category exists
}
```

Comment: Thanks.This will return both exist for all main category Ids

Comment: The will return child category IDs for category ID 4. If its empty there are no sub categories for ID 4.